# How to use perhaps dynamic typing instead of Object in F#?

Tags: dynamic, static, f#, constraints

What I have are some types for a publisher-subscriber:

```
type Subscription<'T> = 'T -> unit
type Subscribers = ConcurrentBag<Object>
type Subscriptions = ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Subscribers>
type PubSub = Subscriptions * PubSubExceptionHandler
```

What I'd like to improve is the `ConcurrentBag<Object>` (ideally to `ConcurrentBag<Subscription>` but the type `'T` that the `Subscription` takes is unknown, so it can't be exposed at the level of `type PubSub<'T>`.  Is my only recourse to use a type constraint?  This seems to preclude using simple records, like `type Counter = {Ctr : int}` as a type that can be subscribed to.  I've been looking at static resolved type constraints (the `^T` notation) but the solution is eluding me.  (And please ignore that I'm using the mutable `ConcurrentBag` - that shouldn't be relevant to the question.)

Comment: Have `Subscription` implement a non-generic interface, and use that in the bag.

Comment: Can't the "and" keyword be used to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

FSharp.Interop.Dynamic https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic/  Has a DLR for dynamic types

However, the comment by 
[Fyodor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180286/fyodor-soikin%22Fyodor%20Soiken%22) about Non-Generic Interfaces would be a good route to take.